# MongoDB - Sum aggregation with conditionals

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I am working on aggregation to perform some analytics on an `Orders` object, I want to get the total price from every order from the previous month, and the total from this month, I tried passing in the `$match` parameter, with the appropriate time conditionals but it's not aggregating any of the data. even though if I perform a `countDocuments` query with the same time conditionals I get a number of documents returned.

```
const totalThis = await Order.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      // should cut the amount of orders off at the beginning of the current month
      createdAt: { $gte: thisMonth.getMonth() + 1 },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      // using $group, _id has to be there or it doesnt
      // return anything, though we dont need an _id
      _id: null,
      total: {
        $sum: "$totalPrice",
      },
    },
  },
]);
res.status(200).json({
  lastMonth: lastMonthSales,
  thisMonth: thisMonthSales,
  totalSalesLast: totalLast,
  totalSalesThis: totalThis,
});
```

In my Postman request, `lastMonth` returns 0, so it would make sense that the array returned to `totalSalesLast` would be empty, however `thisMonth` returns 5 documents, so it should work. Obviously, if I remove the `$match` conditional it will aggregate all the documents, but that's because it's doing ALL the documents and not actually filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query the document with `createdAt` in specific month, your `$match` stage should be as below:

1. `$month` - Take the month value from `createdAt`.
2. `$eq` - Compare both month from (1) and input month are same.

```
{
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $eq: [
        {
          "$month": "$createdAt"
        },
        thisMonth.getMonth() + 1
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E0_tBvanReL)

Comment: This works thanks, can you go into a bit more detail about the $gte part of the answer, I like that it works, but im not following the logic flow.

Comment: Ok, from the above query, we compare month against (input) month. [`$month`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) operator is used to take the month value from the date.

Comment: And also use `$eq`. Updated my answer.